# How to receive user voice through microphone in the Chrome extension panel?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, web-audio-api

I'm using a Chrome extension to display my website as an iframe in the side panel of Chrome.
However, the side panel is not receiving the user's microphone. This is a very important issue because my website aims for real-time interpretation.

I tried giving audioCapture permission in the manifest.json file, and I also tried giving audio permission, but it didn't solve the problem at all.
I tried removing the iframe and using `getUserMedia()` directly, but it didn't seem to work at all, so I became convinced that the side panel wasn't getting the user's voice stream.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using in the question?